# Gutenberg Block Supports: How to set a default background color?

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-plugin-creation

When I add Block Supports for backgroundColor to my custom, dynamic WordPress/Gutenberg block, I would like for the picker to already have a default color selected. [I followed the directions from Reference Guide](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-supports/), but something is missing.

My block.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "my-custom-block",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "My Block Title",
    "category": "widgets",
    "description": "My Block Description",
    "supports": {
        "html": false,
        "color": {
            "background": true,
            "text": false,
            "link": false
        }
    },
    "textdomain": "my-custom-block",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css",
    "attributes": {
        "style": {
            "type": "object",
            "default": {
                "color": {
                    "background": "#b50000"
                }
            }
        },
        "backgroundColor": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "" // The WP Reference Guide says this will be a preset slug. Adding one does not help me.
        }
    }
}
```

My block.php

```
function my_block_init() {
    
    register_block_type('my_custom_block', [
        'render_callback' => 'markup_my_custom_block',
        'attributes' => [
            'backgroundColor' => [
                'type' => 'string',
                'default' => '#b50000'
            ]
        ]
    ] );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_block_init' );
```

My render function (basic at this point)

```
function markup_my_custom_block($attr, $content) {
    return $content;
}
```

My edit.js

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { InnerBlocks, useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import './editor.scss';

/**
 * @return {WPElement} Element to render.
 */

export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {

    return (
        <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
            <InnerBlocks />

        </div>
    );
}
```

My save.js

```
import { InnerBlocks, useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

/**
 * @return {WPElement} Element to render.
 */
export default function save() {
    return (
        <div { ...useBlockProps.save() }>
            <div>
                <InnerBlocks.Content />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**This part works**: The Block Supports background color picker appears as expected and I can set the background color for my block as expected. The block renders with the selected color on the front end.

**Here is where I am stuck**: when the user adds my block, I would like for the picker to already have a default color selected (Instead of showing the circle slash). Since this is a plugin, I would like it to be based on hex rather than a theme color.

I found a couple of tutorials ([including this one](https://gutenberg.10up.com/reference/Blocks/block-supports/#colorbackground)) that say to add the default style to the block.json, but the editor seems to be ignoring it.

I am not getting any JS or PHP errors.

Note: I know that my example here is very simple, but **I really do want to use a dynamic block with a render_callback** function because I am going to add some custom stuff once I learn how to use Block Supports.

**------ Update and Solution ------**

This seems to be a problem with dynamic blocks.

@S.Walsh is correct that the the block.json attributes for default: color make the color picker select a color by default.

As soon as I add 'attributes' (any attributes) to my register_block_type, however, the default color in the editor is ignored. I was able to fix this by adding 'style' as an attribute object to my block.php register_block_type.

The solution is to keep the block.json the way it is and modify the block.php like this:

```
function my_block_init() {
    
    register_block_type('my_custom_block', [
        'render_callback' => 'markup_my_custom_block',
        'attributes' => [
            'style'  => [
                'type'  => 'object',
                'default'  => [
                    'color'  =>
                    [
                        'background'  => '#b50000'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ] );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_block_init' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code by creating a new block and adding your attributes to `block.json` with your edit/save functions. The background color works as expected for the parent block; though when you click inside your block (InnerBlocks > Paragraph) the background color for paragraph (or any InnerBlock added) won't be set as the Paragraph/InnerBlock has its own attributes that aren't inherited from your blocks `block.json`.

[image: Parent block - Background color set]

[image: InnerBlock > Paragraph - No background color set]

Your block.json attributes for default:color:background produced this markup (note: the `has-background` and `background-color` is added as expected):

```html
<!-- wp:create-block/so-75596656 -->
<div class="wp-block-create-block-so-75596656 has-background" style="background-color:#b50000"><div><!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p></p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph --></div></div>
<!-- /wp:create-block/so-75596656 -->
```

If you are not seeing the background default change, run the build process again, remove the block from the page completely then clear the cache before testing readding the block again.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to troubleshoot. 
This has to do with dynamic blocks.
I started over and found that the default color stops working when I add 'attributes' to my block.php register_block_type() . It does not seem to matter what those atts are. I can even leave it empty like:  'attributes' => [] and it will break. Adding style > color > background as on object in register_block_type() seems to fix it though!

'attributes' => [
   'style'  => [
    'type'  => 'object',
    'default'  => [
     'color'  =>
     [
      'background'  => '#b50000'
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]